# Spaces In between the <span> and </span> tags is not displaying

Tags: html

I have the below HTML file.

```
<HTML>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <span>"|      Testing"</span>
    </div>
</body>

</HTML>
```

I want to print `"|      Testing"` , But instead printing that this print `"| Testing"`. What happens to all those `spaces` .

Isn't that code suppose to print what's In  between those `<span>` tags? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: use styles, padding and display:inline-block; if more spans also margin

Comment: @caramba : please tell me how that affect the code. I mean Isn't that code suppose to print what's In  between those < span > tags ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1) about white space characters (emphasis mine):

> Note that a sequence of white spaces between words in the source document may result in an entirely different rendered inter-word spacing (except in the case of the PRE element). In particular, user agents should **collapse input white space** sequences when producing output inter-word space.

So the specification dictates that multiple consecutive spaces should be collapsed into one.

There are a couple of options for "preserving" consecutive spaces:

- Use [CSS to change the way how the browser renders the spaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8zUt/)):

  ```
  span {
      white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
  ```
- You could encode the spaces as `&ensp;` or `&emsp;` (depending on the width of the space you want to insert) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8zUt/1/)) *.
- You could use the [`<pre>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8zUt/5/)):

  ```
  <pre><span>"|      Testing"</span></pre>
  ```

  Since browsers use a different font for the content of `pre` elements, you'd also have to use CSS to reset the font to the font used in the rest of your page, e.g.

  ```
  pre {
      font-family: serif;
  }
  ```

---

*: You could also use the `&nbsp;` HTML entity, however, this change will another behavior of the browser: When the content is too long to fit in the available width of the element, the browser will automatically break the content on spaces. `nbsp` stands for *no-break_space*, so while the browser will render spaces, it won't break overflowing content on them ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6SY2/)).

Answer (score 5):

use `&nbsp;` instead of spaces

```
<span>"|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Testing"</span>
```

Comment: Correct approach,  but you mean &nbsp;

Comment: if (@prime loads data dynamicaly) { it's better to use css instead of $nbsp; } else { $nbsp is OK! } :)

Answer (score 3):

don't use `&nbsp;` in your html. Add a css stylesheet, put a class in your span. add a padding to your span element.

```
<span class="padd">Testing</span>
```

In your stylesheet

```
 span.padd{padding-left:60px;}
```

You could add the '|' before the span tag or just use `span.padd{ border-left: 1px solid #000; }`

Comment: if (@prime loads data dynamicaly) { it's better to use `css` instead of `$nbsp;` } else { `$nbsp` is OK! } :)

Comment: @prime: `&nbsp;` doesn't let the browser break content at that position. That might or might not be what you want.

Comment: because the reason you want spacing is pure cosmetical... With this in mind it's better to keep it in a stylesheet, as stylesheets are to be used for cosmetic reasons...

Answer (score 2):

Multiple spaces in HTML are collapsed and shown as only one space. It's the same reason your line breaks don't all show up and clutter up your text.

You can use `&nbsp;` instead of a space to force insertion of a space. Example:

```
<span>"|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Testing"</span>
```

will display as:

```
"|      Testing"
```

Comment: While browsers handle no-break spaces as non-collapsible, there is really no guarantee of this, and the HTML 4.01 specification explicitly says that it does not define the rendering of such characters.

Comment: That's true, but I have personally never seen an instance of a browser refusing to render a non-breaking space as non-collapsible in a textual context. Can you provide any examples? OP's only other options are to force a space with CSS, use `<pre>` (and style it appropriately), or use transparent `GIF`s, which is obviously not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that browser treat a sequence of space characters as equivalent to a single space. This has always been how browsers behave and what HTML specifications say.

There are ways to change the handling of spaces with CSS or using certain special HTML elements. However, the most flexible approach is to use CSS to add padding (or margin). For example:

```
<style>
.bar { padding-right: 1.25em; }
</style>
...
<span>"<span class=bar>|</span> Testing"</span>
```

The value of `1.2em` in this example roughly corresponds to the width of five spaces (to be used in addition to the spacing caused by space character). The width of a space varies by font. But normally it is best to select the spacing using units like `em`, rather than thinking in terms of amount of spaces.